# debezium kafka msk connector stopped working after including more tables

Tags: debezium, aws-msk

we are using debezium connector for aws msk successfully in the past.
We have performed a recent update where we modified the connector configuration and added 2 more entries in table.include.list.

Subsequently after that the connector started failing with following error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: publication "dbz_publication" does not exist
[Worker-0421d4fe8c53664d4]   Where: slot "debezium", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN 5/50C25428
```

No idea why it started happening. Any help is appreciated.